macOs Terminal zsh: killed mkdir -m 700 -p "$SHELL_SESSION_DIR" at launch
I updated to macOS Sonoma 14.5 a few hours ago and noticed a problem with the terminal. When the terminal is launched, the following message appears:
Last login: Mon May 20 22:00:06 on ttys001
zsh: killed mkdir -m 700 -p "$SHELL_SESSION_DIR"

And when you run different commands such as ls or mkir, the following error message appears:
zsh: killed ls

I've tried several solutions from related questions or from other forums, to no avail. I wonder if anyone has had this kind of problem and would know how to go about it, thanks for your help.
Update :
Here is the erro after trying to execute zsh -f :


I've tried several solutions : I can't see from your post, what you have tried. At the very least, you could have created a shell which does not process any startup files (i.e. zsh -f) and see whether the problem persists.

To add more precision, I try to reinstall zsh, try to resintall homebrew (I had read elsewhere that this could be the cause of the problem but it didn't work because I couldn't execute the command), try to update/upgrade homebrew, try to reinstall the update of macOs and modify path in ~/.zshrc. I also try to create a new user on my mac to see if the problem also appeared or if it's just on my session, and it appeared on both. By the way, i try your solution and the problem persists.

If you still get the error in a subshell created by zsh -f (would you mind sharing a screenshot demonstrating the problem, as I'm not really convinced?), we can at least rule out error in your zsh startup files.

I just updated the post to share a screenshot demonstrating the problem.

What happens with /bin/ls? Also, is this an M1 Mac? Sometimes these symptoms appear when backups or downloads for an Intel Mac are restored to one with Apple chips.

/bin/ls works ! it list all files in the directory. I forgot to mention it but its a Mac Book Air M2 (2022)

Start by fixing the PATH so that /bin is at the front of the list - there are a bunch of posts here on SO about how to do that.  It looks like you have some Intel Mac executables on your system, possibly from using a Time Machine backup to set up this device - make sure the directory that has those is not in the PATH. Clearing out the Intel files is is a non-trivial but non-urgent task; the best way may be to re-install the OS to factory defaults.

I will try out to fixing the PATH. I never used the Time Machine. But why would Intel files be knowing that the M2 chip is Sillicon?

If /bin/ls works but a plain ls doesn't, do a type -a ls and let us know what you see.
